# how to ignore repeated value at sum time?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new in *JasperReports*, I have one report which have tabular data  Table Heading is

```
ID | Product | Amount | Discount 
----------------------------------
 1 | ABC     | 12000  |    10
 1 | ABC     | 12000  |    10
 1 | ABC     | 12000  |    10
 2 | ABC     |  5000  |    20
 2 | ABC     |  5000  |    20
 2 | ABC     |  5000  |    20
 2 | ABC     |  5000  |    20
 3 | ABC     | 13000  |    25
 3 | ABC     | 13000  |    25
```

i want to use built in functionality of *JasperReports* like "print repeated value is unchecked" its display is not show repeated but when i try to do sum of amount it will give 
the all amount sum but i want to get out put like 12000+5000+13000 only

so how can i get the result?

I WANT TO GET RESULT LIKE THIS

```
ID | Product | Amount | Discount 
----------------------------------
 1 | ABC     | 12000  |    10
   | ABC     |        |    
   | ABC     |        |    
 2 | XYZ     |  5000  |    20
   | XYZ     |        |    
   | XYZ     |        |    
   | XYZ     |        |    
 3 | PQR     | 13000  |    25
   | PQR     |        |    
----------------------------------
 Total         30000       55   
----------------------------------
```

Comment: also i want to hide the Amount and discount and id field  which has same id

Comment: What output results do you expect to get?

Comment: What is the `<queryString>` of your report?